# Change label of UIpopoverViewController

Tags: swift

on my MainView I have a button. With a click on the button the popoverView will be shown. 
My popoverView is a subclass of an UIViewController. In this popoverView I also have a button. When I click on that button, I want to change a label of the popoverView:

```
 @IBAction func awayClicked(sender: AnyObject) {
 awayLabel.text! = "\(Int(arc4random_uniform(7)))"
 }
```

But the label will be changed short-term and afterwards recessed to previous value. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting up this popover in a storyboard, a new instance of the view controller and its view hierarchy (including the label) will be created each time it is displayed.  If you want the value you set to the label text to persist between instances being created, you will have to store it somewhere (potentially in `NSUserDefaults`) and retrieve it when the view loads again in the future (typically done in an override of the `UIViewController` `viewWillAppear` method).

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for.Tell me if it helps

```
@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
            {
                didSet
                {
                        textView.text = text

                }
            }

        var text : String = ""
            {
                    didSet
                    {
                            textView?.text = text
                    }
            }

        override var preferredContentSize : CGSize

            {
            get
            {
                if textView != nil && presentingViewController != nil
                {
                    return textView.sizeThatFits(presentingViewController!.view.bounds.size)
                }
                else
                {
                    return super.preferredContentSize
                }
            }

            set {super.preferredContentSize = newValue}

            }
```

Comment: Yeah, this works! Can you explain me how it works? And how can i change this that i can change the titleLabel of a button?

Comment: you are not changing the title. you are just adding more thing to it. Think it as an array. Where this array get printed as a popvoer:) the override i did there is very important in order to get a small sized popover based on the text size so it comes handy some times. What exactly do you need to know? what you mean titleLabel? i guess you mean the inner stuff that gets presented

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. With the titleLable I mean the label of a button. In the popover I have a button and on the button click I want to change the label of the button. But with that extension this did't worked for me.